# fatal error 9001 while login into asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, database

This is the second time I got following error for my website:

> Warning: Fatal error 9001 occurred at May  5 2012  1:16AM. Note the
>   error and time, and contact your system administrator.

I get this error while login to website. However, there is no any problem for connecting database or fetching records.

Last time I just took a backup and restore my database then this issue was resolved. But, I got again similar issue, now I want to know exact cause for this error.

I appreciate your reply.

Comment: How exactly did you "get" this error? Is it in your logs? The system event log? In a result page?

Comment: @Ashwini But you still haven't answered his question.

Comment: coming on the point. I get this on result page; after login button press. I check the database connectivity and successfully fetched the record but this error only while login.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma: So it's presumably due to an exception? Please log the complete stack trace of the exception, including any inner exceptions.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma Check SQL Server logs, seems to be an issue with log being full, check Google for "Fatal error 9001". Also "Last time I just took a backup and restore my database then this issue was resolved." seems to be database related.

Comment: @TomasVoracek: "seems to be an issue with log being full" may be you are right. So, there is no solution except database backup.

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/238394/diagnosing-microsoft-sql-server-error-9001-the-log-for-the-database-is-not-avai

Comment: @TomasVoracek: thanks! above link was really helpful.

Comment: Maybe the log file (of event viewer, or database) is full and not recycle by default, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check SQL Server logs, seems to be an issue with log being full. "Last time I just took a backup and restore my database then this issue was resolved." seems to be database related. Check https://serverfault.com/questions/238394/diagnosing-microsoft-sql-server-error-9001-the-log-for-the-database-is-not-avai.